# Validating user input in batch

Tags: batch-file

I've got a simple batch script:

```
@echo off
set cash=500
:a
set name=
set /p input=Enter your name:
echo %name%
goto :a
```

I know batch input is prone to exploitation,and I've read a lot of articles on that. I can stop the user from just typing `input&&set cash=100000` but how do i stop the batch file from closing if the user enters the `|` character?

Comment: I've added a lot of validation code, (even stopping the user from typing "set  variable=" among other things. But it's that darn "|" that's the problem.

Comment: Use delayed expansion.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the echo command, not the input routine.
Double quotes fixes that - there are other ways.

```
@echo off
set cash=500
:a
set name=
set /p name=Enter your name:
echo "%name%"
goto :a
```

Comment: nice. but that does not stop the "|" problem now does it? Maybe i should pipe a c++ exe that does what i want.

Comment: Yes, it stops the problem that you asked about.  Being unaware about echoing poison characters is where you were tripped up.